# Fluid in lungs from pressure during bowel movement?

Tags: covid-19, lungs, chest, abdominal, covid

One of my relatives is admitted in the hospital because he got infected with COVID. And yesterday, his lungs had fluid in them because he exerted pressure during defecation.

How is this possible? Pressure in the lower abdomen affecting the chest? I'm not understanding it. Also I can't meet the doctor incharge so that option of inquiry was closed. But I'm very curious to understand this and would appreciate if someone provided insights. Also I thought it'd be an interesting case for you'll as well!

Comment: You received this information second hand, and I think what you were told was a misinterpretation. Most likely the COVID is solely responsible for the fluid in the lungs and the bowel movement was purely coincidental. But that's speculation on my part, which is all anyone here can offer. In general, bowel movements don't cause fluid to accumulate in the lungs.